# spread operator and update to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I have an array list from server in gridItems which I create a copy of & use the spread operator

```
let gridItems = this.get('sectionInformation.gridItems');
this.get('sectionInformation.someRows').pushObject(gridItems);
var updatedContainers = [...gridItems];
set(this.get('sectionInformation'), 'someRows', updatedContainers);

self.get('sectionInformation.someRows').forEach(function(container) {
    self._updateFieldsForSomeRows(container.fields);
});

_updateFieldsForSomeRows: function(fields, seqNum) {
    // Inside this, I do
    fields.forEach(function(field){
        set(field, 'someAttr', 'someVal');
    });
    //After above code is run, I expected that this should affect the fields inside sectionInformation.someRows. However, it instead updates in "gridItems". Not sure why that is the case
}
```

My question is for some reason, it is affecting only the original reference & not sectionInformation.someRows

Comment: Spreading does a shallow copy. If the elements of `gridItems` are objects, and you're modifying properties of those objects, and you want `gridItems` to remain unmodified, you'd need to do a deep copy. I'm not entirely sure if that's your goal, though.

Comment: Yes, despite iterating on "someRows" and passing individual element from "someRows", what actually gets updated is the property inside "gridItems". I am fine with property inside "gridItems" getting modified, but what I really want is the property inside "someRows" to be modified

Comment: Then you'd need to do a deep clone, either manually or via a library (e.g., lodash or whatever).

Comment: Oh k...Any reference link would be really helpful. Thanks.